# Download file from server

Tags: asp.net, download, ashx

I have an ASP.NET/C# page. It basically has a textbox to accept user input. The data is processed on the server and a file is generated and saved.

Initially I transmitted the file to the client using `Response.TransmitFile()`. However, this process disables the javascript on the page when the file is downloaded.

Therefore, I have designed a .ashx handler to help download the file.

Now, there are two buttons on the page. The user clicks on one to process and create the file. Once the page postbacks, the other button is enabled and should be clicked to download the file (invoke the handler).

What I want to know is how I can wire up the button to call the handler?

Note: I need to send a parameter to the handler as a query string. This parameter is available ONLY in the code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specifically want a button, for the request, you could take this approach:

ASPX:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDownloadFile" runat="server" OnClick="btnDownloadFile_Click" />
```

Code-Behind:

```
protected void btnDownloadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(string.Format("/File.ashx?Id={0}", MyParameter);
}
```

Comment: I figured this out myself a few minutes ago! But thanks anyway!
I was under the impression that the Redirect would actually redirect me to a blank page or something.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to implicitly invoke the handler after the page postsback. Could you shed some light on this?

Comment: Implicitly, not that I'm aware but maybe you can tell me what problems you are still having?  First, let me help clarify on the handler (and maybe you know this already)...if you look at System.Web.Page on MSDN, you will notice that it implements IHttpHandler just like you are doing with your custom ASHX.  In essence a Page is just a handler with some additional lifecycle capabilities.  Might help you think about what you can do with them from a code-behind standpoint.

Comment: It's not actually a problem of sorts. I don't want the user to click a button to download the file. When the user clicks the first button, is there a way to first process and create the file on the server and redirect to the handler when the file is ready?

Comment: Oohhh...of course.  I didn't grasp that from your first question.  I would need to know how you are generating the file.  Is it an asynchronous process?  (can you share a snippet of code for that first button click)

Comment: It's actually quite a long drawn process. In short, I am making use of 4 `BackgroundWorkers` to run 4 parallel queries, the results of which are stored in a dataset of datatables. I then export the dataset to an excel file stored on the server.
If I use `Response.Redirect("/Download.ashx?Id="+ ID);` when all 4 workers have completed, the download is invoked but I lose the javascript functionality of the page.

Comment: I'll do my best with limited visibility into that but I worry my answer will be too simplistic without further details.  I'm assuming you know when all that processing finishes via `RunWorkerCompleted` callback. Given that you are enabling the second button, you must know the file was created already.  If that is true, why not simply just do the Response.Redirect to your Handler at that point and eliminate the second button call completely?

Comment: That is precisely what I said. If I use Response.Redirect to the Handler at this point, the javascript functionality on the page is lost (I disable the button on click). When the page postsback it should automatically be re-enabled. But that does not happen if I use Response.Redirect in the first request itself.

Answer (score 1):

I know you specifically are asking about buttons but you could make the second button a hyperlink instead that is styled like the button and set the NavigationUrl (or href) to the .ashx path.  I'm making some assumptions about the code of your handler but since its a handler, you can directly invoke it via an HTTP GET request.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkDownloadFile" runat="server" NavigationUrl="/File.ashx?Id=1" Text="Download File" />
```

or

```
<a href="/File.ashx?Id=1">Download File</a>
```

If you need to set the parameter in the codebehind, you can set it in one of the Lifecycle events such as Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     lnkDownloadFile.NavigationUrl = string.Format("/File.ashx?Id={0}", MyParameterValue);
}
```

Comment: This is another good way that I could do it. But the previous one works! Anyway thanks for the help!